# How to Combine 2 Line Graphs Together

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to using R so please bear with me as my code might not look the best. So I want to combine these two line graphs together since right now I have written code for each item that I am analyzing. This is the dataset I am using: https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/blob/master/data/2020/2020-09-01/readme.md I used the "Arable_Land" dataset!

```
##USA Arable Land
plot_arable_land_USA <- arable_land %>%
  filter(Code == "USA") %>%
  select(c(Year, Code, `Arable land needed to produce a fixed quantity of crops ((1.0 = 1961))`)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Year, Code)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value,color=name,group=name)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(.~name,scales = 'free_y') +
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')

ggplotly(plot_arable_land_USA)

##Canada Arable Land
plot_arable_land_CAN <- arable_land %>%
  filter(Code == "CAN") %>%
  select(c(Year, Code, `Arable land needed to produce a fixed quantity of crops ((1.0 = 1961))`)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Year, Code)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value,color=name,group=name)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(.~name,scales = 'free_y') +
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')

ggplotly(plot_arable_land_CAN)
```

Ideally, I would like one graph to show both like one line (in Purple) to show the USA and another line(in Brown) to show Canada.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It is a better practice to reshape data to long as you did. In your case you can add `filter()` to choose the desired countries. Then, reshape to long and design the plot. The key is setting `color` and `group` with `Code` in order to obtain the desired lines. You can set the colors using `scale_color_manual()` and I have left the facet option to get the title. Here the code:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
#Code
plot_arable_land_CAN <- arable_land %>% select(-Entity) %>%
  filter(Code %in% c('USA','CAN')) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Code,Year)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value,color=Code,group=Code)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(.~name,scales = 'free_y') +
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('brown','purple'))
#Transform
ggplotly(plot_arable_land_CAN)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Wow, you are so good! Can you please explain why you added `select(-Entity)`?

Comment: @Marce Sure, that was used to exclude that variable as it is not contributing to the plot. If you want to keep it, you can remove that line of code and set `pivot_longer(-c(Entity,Code,Year))`. It is just a manner to format the data. I hope that was clear enough for you :)